# Regularity of PDE with respect to coefficients?

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, regularity-theory-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

Consider for example, the Black Schole's equation

$\partial_tu+0.5\sigma^2s^2\partial_{ss}u+rs\partial_su-ru=0$

Subject to boundary conditions

$u(s,T)=f(s)$ and $u(0,t)=g(t)$

The solution depends on the parameter $\sigma$, which is not a variable in the PDE, but it is possible to show the solution is differentiable with respect to $\sigma$ for certain f and g. Do there exists analysis tools and results which deal with smoothness of solutions with respect to perturbation of coefficients of PDEs?

Comment: This is a big subject; I'd say the beginning is with bifurcation theory.

Comment: @Ian care to elaborate a little please?

Comment: In the cases I am interested in, there should be no qualitative change.

Comment: Bifurcation theory happens where there is qualitative change, but it is closely related to the description of the changes within each qualitative regime. Roughly speaking, away from a bifurcation, the dependence on parameters is smooth. This of course requires hypotheses, and I don't know the most general ones. For instance I would expect the smoothing in something like the heat equation to be sufficient, while the regularity-reducing effects in the wave equation would probably block such a result.

Comment: @Ian do you have anything to suggest which may help me to answer prove what i said is true in the example i gave?

Comment: [Here are some relevant slides](http://main3.amu.edu.pl/~domanski/gf07.pdf). I suppose that the strategy is to identify function spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that your PDO is a bijection from $X$ onto (affine subspace of) $Y$. Then the Neumann series can represents the inverse operator as a power series in terms of $\sigma$, showing analyticity.

Comment: @HomegrownTomato do you know if it is a problem if the boundary condition also depends on sigma. (and the notes looks dense! I think it will serve as a good starting point to find something which assumes less)

Comment: No, this shouldn't be a problem. In fact, I would probably subtract off some function that interpolates between boundary condition, reducing the problem to homogeneous BCs and nonhomogeneous PDE $L_\sigma (u)=F_\sigma$. Then if $L_\sigma^{-1}$ has analytic dependency on $\sigma$, the result follows. One more reference, though specialized: [Corollary 7.16, page 65](https://books.google.com/books?id=8iZczAQc59cC) on "Beltrami Equation" by Iwaniec and Martin. For the Beltrami PDE, the holomorphic dependence on parameter is pretty important, so it was studied in detail.